# SSRS SQL Parameter = null or not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to build a report in SSRS that would allow the report user to pick a specific task in our system and then decide if the report they want to pull has had the task completed or not.

If the task has been completed, in the SQL world, the code would be:

```
WHERE <date> is not null 
or
WHERE <date> is null
```

I am unable to figure out how to pass this through a parameter in a way that SQL accepts.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the Parameter Data Type to Text and then for Available Values I would Specify value of Yes and No.

Then your SQL code needs to look for that e.g.

WHERE  is null AND @Date_Null = 'Yes'